# Unable to npm install secp256k1

Tags: python, c++, node.js

I have searched through stack overflow following other helpful advice for node-gyp as well as the prerequisites dicussed in https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp, but have still have this build error:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\bajor\Desktop\Development\hackathon-starter\node_modules\secp256k1
gyp ERR! node -v v6.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "rebuild"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! secp256k1@3.1.0 rebuild: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the secp256k1@3.1.0 rebuild script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the secp256k1 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs secp256k1
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls secp256k1
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here is my set up:

- Windows 10 x64
- node-gyp installed globally
- VS2015 with C++ build tools, windows 8.1 tools and SDKS, windows 10 SDK
- Python 2.7.12 with PATH and configured for node
- Ran: npm config set msvs_version 2015
- Ran: npm config set python C:\Python27

When trying other packages that require node-gyp such as node-sass, there is no build issues, but with secp256k1 I am encountering the issue.

Also I keep getting the same warning multiple times right before the error:

```
warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to '
unsigned char', possible loss of data (compiling source file ..\src\secp256k1-src\s
rc\secp256k1.c)
```

Comment: Is there no output before the "build error" line?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `npm` try using `yarn` to install `secp256k1`:

```
yarn add secp256k1
```